# Draw Editable Line

Tags: iphone, objective-c, drawing, line

How to draw Editable Line like this application http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=F0GaOAXXsa8
in iPhone . I have try but i am can't draw like this app. please help me for draw line.

Comment: I want to develop draw line and Angle like this application

Comment: Same as this application i have try to draw line but i can't put drag and resize line

Comment: Just give me idea about above application i will create for that

Answer (score 0):

1. Subclass a `UIView`.
2. Implement `drawRect:` to draw the background image first and the line on top of it with Core Graphics. The line endpoints can be kept as the view's instance variables.
3. Implement `touchesBegan:withEvent:` to record the line's first end point.
4. In `touchesMoved:withEvent:` record the line's second end point and call `[self setNeedsDisplay]` to update the drawing.
5. In `touchesEnded:withEvent:` finalize the process as needed.